# Convert pipe-delimited files to .xls

Tags: excel, batch-file, vbscript

I'm trying to convert pipe-delimited files to xls (Excel) with batch file and vbscript. Unfortunately, my "output.xls" file is still showing the pipe delimiter in the table and the data are not organized.

```
srccsvfile = Wscript.Arguments(0)  
tgtxlsfile = Wscript.Arguments(1)  

'Create Spreadsheet
'Look for an existing Excel instance.
On Error Resume Next ' Turn on the error handling flag
Set objExcel = GetObject(,"Excel.Application")
'If not found, create a new instance.
If Err.Number = 429 Then  '> 0
  Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
End If

objExcel.Visible = false
objExcel.displayalerts=false

'Import CSV into Spreadsheet
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.open(srccsvfile)
Set objWorksheet1 = objWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

'Adjust width of columns
Set objRange = objWorksheet1.UsedRange
objRange.EntireColumn.Autofit()
'This code could be used to AutoFit a select number of  columns
'For intColumns = 1 To 17
'    objExcel.Columns(intColumns).AutoFit()
'Next

'Make Headings Bold
objExcel.Rows(1).Font.Bold = TRUE

'Freeze header row
With objExcel.ActiveWindow
     .SplitColumn = 0
     .SplitRow = 1
End With
objExcel.ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True

'Add Data Filters to Heading Row
objExcel.Rows(1).AutoFilter

'set header row gray
objExcel.Rows(1).Interior.ColorIndex = 15
'-0.249977111117893


'Save Spreadsheet, 51 = Excel 2007-2010 
objWorksheet1.SaveAs tgtxlsfile, 51

'Release Lock on Spreadsheet
objExcel.Quit()
Set objWorksheet1 = Nothing
Set objWorkbook = Nothing
Set ObjExcel = Nothing
```

source :http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1682555

Comment: A pipe-delimited file isn't the same thing as a CSV file: you'll need to use the `OpenText` method, not `Workbooks.Open`  Try recording a macro while doing that, and then incorporate that into your VBScript file.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837097.aspx  In Excel: http://www.udel.edu/itwebdev/help/import/import.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pipe doesn't equal Comma, Excel natively knows what to do with a CSV, but not with Pipe.

All is not lost, record your actions opening the file manually, once open highlight column A and click Data / Text To Columns, choose delimited and in the "other" box put a pipe then click next, choose the column formats (great to format numbers as text if you need to like Postcodes and phone numbers) then click finish.

Now stop the recorder and look at the code it generated. Port this over to your Excel object in your script.

Comment: run macro from VBS? How.

Comment: Port the code, use your excel object to send the macro commands, not to run the macro in excel

Answer (score 1):

Excel is a little picky when it comes to reading CSV files. If you have a delimited file with the extension `.csv` Excel will only open it correctly via the `Open` method if the delimiter is the character configured in the system's regional settings.

The [`Open`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194819.aspx) method has optional parameters that allow you to specify a custom delimiter character (credit to @Jeeped for pointing this out):

```
set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(srccsvfile, , , 6, , , , , "|")
```

You can also use the [`OpenText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837097.aspx) method (which will be used when recording the action as a macro):

```
objExcel.Workbooks.OpenText srccsvfile, , , 1, , , , , , , True, "|"
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks(1)
```

Note that the `OpenText` method does not return a workbook object, so you must assign the workbook to a variable yourself after opening the file.

**Important:** either way your file **must not** have the extension `.csv` if your delimiter character differs from your system's regional settings, otherwise the delimiter will be ignored.

Comment: Doesn't the [Workbooks Open method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa195811(v=office.11).aspx) allow for a specific delimiter as well?

Comment: @Jeeped Apparently [it does](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194819.aspx). When was this introduced? I seem to recall that back in the day `OpenText` was the only way to achieve this. Updated answer.

Comment: Not sure about the circa of the change. FWIW, the [Workbooks.OpenText method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837097.aspx) does provide for more of the options found in the GUI's Text Import Wizard (close cousin of the Text-to-Columns wizard).